# In a game where all three players have the same odds of winning, which is more probable? A winning 3 out of 4 games, or A winning 5 out of 8 games?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

I understand that I should use the Binomial Distribution formula, which gives me $\frac{8}{81}$ and $\frac{448}{3^8} $ respectively, but shouldn't I get to the same result just by considering all the possible distributions of 4 wins among the 3 players? There's $\binom {6}{2}$ distributions and I thought dividing the 2 possibilities where A gets three wins by this number would get me to the result as well. Clearly my assumption is incorrect, but I struggle to visualize where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because all outcomes are not necessarily equally likely to occur. For instance, A winning $7$ out of $8$ games is much less likely than A winning $3$ out of $8$.

Comment: I've completely overlooked that, thanks.